# Positioning a child behind his parent with his a fixed position

Tags: css, position, z-index, fixed

So here is my problem, I have a music player wich have a volume button. When I press the volume button, a box appear under the button. Since my background isn't flat, I want to put that box behind the background. I tried to play with the negative z-index, but it didn't worked. Can you guys help me out? Here's a link, the music player is on the top screen (position fixed) http://hateittoo.com/?page=shows

PS: The website works better with Google Chrome for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `volume_controls` so it's not nested in `music_player`.  `z-index` cannot go below what the parent element is.

```
<div id="music_player"><!-- has background image you're trying to hide controls under -->
    ... 
    <div class="content" id="volume_controls" style="display: block;">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

to tuck it behind the bg without `z-index` move your `volume_controls` element just above `music_player`

Comment: I guess I won't have the choice ^^ Thx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot position a child behind his parent. You will need to take out the volume div from the player div, make them both fixed and then use `z-index`.